# Lightning Knowledge Summary field retrieval not possible

Tags: lightning, deployment, metadata-api, lightning-knowledge

I am trying to retrieve Knowledge__kav Object "Summary" field but not able to, I want to remove HelpText of Summary field and then deploy it, is it possible?

```
<types>
 <members>Knowledge__kav.Summary</members>
 <name>CustomField</name>
</types>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the SFDX folder, Navigate to the folder, `objects` -> `Knowledge__kav` -> `fields`

In the `fields` folder, create a new file named `Summary__c.field-meta.xml`

Now open the project in VSCode, navigate to `Summary__c.field-meta.xml`. Retrieve it, make changes and re-deploy.

Comment: CustomField  Entity of type 'CustomField' named 'Knowledge__kav.Summary__c' cannot be found - This error comes while retriving